# How to build SPFX Web Part with Angular CLI Elements

Tags: angular, sharepoint, spfx, angular-elements, sharepointframework

When using gulp serve - Getting errors like
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

I am trying to follow
https://www.spjeff.com/2021/10/24/video-how-to-build-spfx-web-part-with-angular-cli-elements/

I also tried to use PnP-SPFX, but still same issue.

Need guidance on how to use angular with SPFX. Preferably with latest version of SPFx v1.16 and Angular 15. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks